# Mongo - I can't save Pojo with java-mongo 3.5 driver (if it contains Map<String,Object> or Document field)

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to use mongo java driver 3.5 which allows you to save pojo (it automatically maps it to bson). http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/

This pojo contains a field of type Map (it is called dynabean):

```
private String signature;
private Map<String, Object> properties = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

When I try to save it, I get:

```
CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Object
```

I tried replacing this map with Document:

```
private String signature;
private Document properties;
```

but when I try to save pojo object that contains a document - it doesn't work:

```
CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class my.test.case.PojoWithDocument
```

To sum up: I can save a Document, I can save a Pojo, but I cannot save a Pojo that contains document. And I cannot save a Pojo that contains a `Map<String, Object>`.

How can I deal with it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java mongo driver 3.6 , you should be able to save the Pojo that contains document.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Fix for Map is planned for version 3.7 (https://jira.mongodb.org issue: JAVA-2695)